opencart php mysql max min price filter
i have some problem but ı dont solved problem ı want make filter sistem ı find max min price but ı want bring product_id
$sql = "SELECT max(coalesce((SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1), " .
               "(SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1), " .
               "p.price) ) AS max_price, min(coalesce((SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1), " .
               "(SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1), " .
               "p.price) ) AS min_price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p" .
               " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value pov ON (pov.product_id=p.product_id)" .
               " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p2s.product_id=p.product_id)";

output
Array
(
    [max_price] => 3477.3499
    [min_price] => 58.3333
)

Array
(
    [max_price] => 3477.3499
    [max_product_id] => 1254
    [min_price] => 58.3333
    [min_product_id] => 1255
)


Where are you expecting these min/max product_id values to come from? The current correlated subqueries are correlated on p.product_id so any max or min would still be p.product_id? If this is not the case, please update your question with the table structures, sample data and desired output.
